# I cannot access audited association on models after switching from SQLite3 to MySQL in Rails 4.2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sqlite

I have been using the gem `audited` in my rails application.  At first I was using a sqlite3 database but have recently switched over to MySQL. When I attempt to access my association that the gem provides (ex: myObject.audits) I get the following error.

```
`ArgumentError: undefined class/module ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3String
    from /home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/class_loader.rb:53:in `path2class'
    from /home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/class_loader.rb:53:in `resolve'
    from /home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/class_loader.rb:45:in `find'
    from /home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/class_loader.rb:27:in `load'
    from /home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:360:in `resolve_class'
    from /home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:203:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
    from /home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
    from /home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
    from /home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:31:in `accept'
    from /home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:302:in `block in revive_hash'
    from /home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:300:in `each'
    from /home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:300:in `each_slice'
    from /home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:300:in `revive_hash'
    from /home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:161:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
    from /home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
    from /home/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
... 63 levels...
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_set.rb:31:in `fetch_value'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:93:in `_read_attribute'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:87:in `read_attribute'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:305:in `attribute_for_inspect'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:443:in `block in inspect'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:441:in `collect'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:441:in `inspect'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:629:in `map!'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:629:in `inspect'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'2.1.3 :004 >`
```

I'm not sure where to start debugging this error.  Can anyone provide some direction? Thanks!

Comment: `psych` is a YAML engine. That suggests that your gem is using `serialize` to store a hash in the database but somehow it is somehow putting `SQLite3String` instances into the hash rather than plain Ruby `String`s. Yet another reason that `serialize` the work of the devil. You have 2 problems: (1) throw out or manually convert all the existing `serialize`d data (2) Figure out what is putting that screwy data into the database. I don't know enough about the gem or how it works to give you a proper answer, sorry.

Comment: @muistooshort, no sorry needed! This is very helpful I'll start looking into both and I'll update this post... or perhaps someone with more knowledge than myself can contribute. Thanks!

Comment: I believe this could be corrected by converting the database column alone.  I deleted all records in my development database and then made a change to the object and this solved the issue. I've not found a way yet to convert the column though.

Comment: The problem is that the database column contains YAML and that YAML contains serialized `SQLite3String` instances. So converting the column requires the right `SQLite3String` class around. You might want to examine the YAML inside your MySQL database to make sure you're not repeating your SQLite problem with MySQL.